# Logistic function Addition or subtraction

Tags: machine-learning, theano, logistic-regression

I'm currently studying Machine Learning but I don't have a statistics background. Everywhere I've seen the logistic function, it has always been:

```
wx + b
```

but [this example in Theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html#a-real-example-logistic-regression) used:

```
wx - b
```

Please which one is it? I'm new to this and I don't want to get confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example on your linked page is not using `wx - b`. Here is the formula I assume you are referencing:

```
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-T.dot(x, w) - b))
```

You can break this up into the sigmoid argument and the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function):

```
arg = T.dot(x, w) + b         # sigmoid argument
p_1 = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-arg))   # sigmoid function
```

So there are two issues. The first is that you didn't factor the sign of the `b` variable properly (the formula *is* using `wx + b`). Second is that the formula you quoted isn't actually the sigmoid function; rather, it is the argument (a linear weighted sum of input variables) that is passed *to* the sigmoid function.

Comment: `T.dot(x, w) - b` and `T.dot(x, w) + b` look like 2 different things. I get that you can use the subtraction if you wanted, but I'm just beginning.

Comment: I deleted the note from my answer to eliminate confusion. The point was that as long as you handle it consistently, it doesn't matter.